# how to get folder security properties on windows using java

Tags: java

I want to check for the given folder path(local path,shared path) and credentials for the folder, whether user has access to this folder.

In windows, we can verify that by manually by right click on that folder and go to security tab.

I read some posts, but most of them are suggesting to create a file in that folder and then delete it to verify it. I am restricted to do that in my requirement.

please help me if we can do that it in java

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new file with the given path:

   File testFile = new File("path");
2. If canRead:

   if(file.canRead()) {
     // do something
   }

For a complete list of what you can do with java.io.File, please visit the API (you can try/catch to delete, write, etc):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

The `File` class has several useful methods to achieve what you want:

```
File file = new File("path-to-file");
System.out.println(file.exists());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(file.getParent());
System.out.println(file.canRead());
System.out.println(file.canWrite());
System.out.println(file.isHidden());
```

For more info, try using the official docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

---

**EDIT**

As per OP's comment, here's a way to check a file's owner and the file's permissions:

```
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("path");
    UserPrincipal owner = null;
    Set<PosixFilePermission> posixFilePermissions = null;
    try {
        owner = Files.getOwner(path);
        posixFilePermissions = Files.getPosixFilePermissions(path);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestCenter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println(owner);
    System.out.println(posixFilePermissions);
```

Output (the file has 664 permission on my Linux machine):

```
victor
[OWNER_WRITE, OWNER_READ, OTHERS_READ, GROUP_WRITE, GROUP_READ]
```

Comment: This is virtually identical to my earlier response

Comment: @Matt Uhm. True. I thought I should post some examples, because from the way OP expressed himself, he didn't seem to have much experience, and perhaps wouldn't find it so easy to browse through the docs. I apologize if I hurt some SO ethics on the way.

Comment: doesn't hurt my feelings... your examples are good as well.  The point is to help others.

Comment: Thanks all, but my question is if the folder is access restricted how can check if the path is accessible for that user. I am given with user and password for that path. so how do we programatically access the folder